# Install Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on X230 grub error

Tags: grub2, thinkpad, x230

When I try to install Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on my Thinkpad x230 it returns with this error:  can't install GRUB on /dev/mmcblk0

Comment: In your BIOS, is the disk setting set to RAID, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some strange reasons Ubuntu isntaller tried to install the bootloader on the USB and not on the hard drive. 
Go to manual resize and partition creator install and select your hard drive for the bootloader /dev/sda

Answer (score -1):

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on an old IBM Think Pad T60. Near the end I got a similar error. There are a lot of solutions posted around, some using a boot-repair program, others involving post-install repair with the live (off the DVD) Linux. Here is what worked for me after some experimentation:

Using 17.04 32 bit i-386 ISO image, burned to DVD, I cold booted, and used the following options on the Ubuntu install. These choices are approximate, but you'll recognize them in the actual installation choices

Full install with delete

LVM

install updates now

load extras like fonts and graphics

I am guessing either the grub with the updates is fixed, or using LVM (no tweaking, just took what it gave me) fixed the boot record bug.

Comment: What works in old machines is irrelevant for new UEFI machines.